# How to repeat code after asking the user to play again?

Tags: python

I have to make a "pick a number" game that, once you play it once, should prompt the option play it again and keep playing. How can I use the code I created before when it asked the user for the first time again to play the game again?

```
again = input("Would you like to play again?(Enter yes or no): ").lower().strip()
if again == "yes": 
  int(input("Pick a number from 1-10: "))

# What do I write here, instead of just rewriting the code I did above?
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import random

score = 0  
games = 0 

print("Welcome to pick a number!")

guess = int(input("Pick a number from 1-10: "))

rnum = random.randint(1,10)
guess = int(guess)

while True: 
  games += 1
  if 10 > guess < 1:
    print("Sorry that input was not valid")
    x = int(input("Pick a number from 1-10: "))
  if guess == rnum:
    score +=1
    print("The number was", rnum, "You got a point!")
    print("Current Score:",score)
  else: 
    score +=0
    print("The number was", rnum, "Sorry you didn't get a point.")
    print("Current Score:",score)
  break
  
again = input("Would you like to play again?(Enter yes or no): ").lower().strip()
if again == "yes": 
  int(input("Pick a number from 1-10: "))

if again == "no":
  print("You got", score, "out of", games, "games correct.")
```

Comment: Put everything that you want looped in a loop; your current loop will become a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking your `while` loop at the wrong time. `break` it if the user says no:

```py
import random

score = 0  
games = 0 

print("Welcome to pick a number!")

while True: 

  guess = int(input("Pick a number from 1-10: "))

  rnum = random.randint(1,10)
  guess = int(guess)
  games += 1
  if 10 > guess < 1:
    print("Sorry that input was not valid")
    x = int(input("Pick a number from 1-10: "))
  if guess == rnum:
    score +=1
    print("The number was", rnum, "You got a point!")
    print("Current Score:",score)
  else: 
    score +=0
    print("The number was", rnum, "Sorry you didn't get a point.")
    print("Current Score:",score)
  
  again = input("Would you like to play again?(Enter yes or no): ").lower().strip()

  if again == "no":
    print("You got", score, "out of", games, "games correct.")
    break
```

Make sure you request input from the user from the loop itself (I have done that for you)

Answer (score -1):

In your code, after asking the user if they want to play again and checking their input, there are two separate if statements that check if the input is "yes" or "no", respectively. However, **these if statements are not part of a loop, so they do not create a repeating behavior.** After checking the input, the code simply moves on to the next line, which is not what you want in this case.

To enable the user to play the game again without manually rerunning the code, you need to enclose the game logic in a while loop, that repeats as long as the user answers "yes" to the "Would you like to play again?". This allows the code to keep prompting the user for input and updating the game state until the user decides to stop playing.

Here is the complete code, to enhance the functionality, I also incorporated lines addressing the problem of non-numeric inputs by users:

```html
import random

def main():
    score = 0
    games = 0

    print("Welcome to pick a number!")

    while True:
        try:
            guess = int(input("Pick a number from 1-10: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, that input was not valid. Please enter a number.")
            continue

        rnum = random.randint(1, 10)

        if guess < 1 or guess > 10:
            print("Sorry, that number is out of the valid range.")
            continue

        if guess == rnum:
            score += 1
            print("The number was", rnum, "You got a point!")
            print("Current Score:", score)
        else:
            print("The number was", rnum, "Sorry you didn't get a point.")
            print("Current Score:", score)

        games += 1

        again = input("Would you like to play again? (Enter yes or no): ").lower().strip()
        if again == "yes":
            continue
        elif again == "no":
            print("You got", score, "out of", games, "games correct.")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input. Exiting the game.")
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```